# Try to connect onos contrller in remote sever's container

Tags: docker, controller, sdn, mininet, onos

I try to connect onos contrller in remote sever's container. But it shows `Unable to contact the remote controller at 129.00.09.82:8190`
The mininet command is `sudo mn --topo=linear,3 --controller=remote,ip= 129.00.09.82:8190`
The Ip I used is floating Ip
Then I use the command `sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller s1 tcp:129.00.09.82:8190:6653` to set controller. It failed.

But if I run mininet on the same sever as docker container
I use the command `sudo mn --topo=linear,3 --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1:8190`
and set use this command `sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller s1 tcp:172.17.0.2:6653`
I succeed.
I know the success from karaf@root > when I type devices, it shows connected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `ping 129.00.09.82`is responding.

If you can ping successfully but cannot connect.

Check that Onos contrller application `Openflow Provide suite` is started.